# How to recover a directory and all its contents from an XFS File System on Centos 7

Tags: linux

This post has been modified as I have now found out that the file system on our Centos Boxes use XFS.

I have been reading about debugfs and how it can be used to recover deleted files. However, I have not been able to find or see an example where it be used to recover a directory containing sub directories and its contents to a new directory on the file system.

Or is there a simple way of recovering directories and files on an XFS file system. I am looking for a solution for a Live mounted server

Does anyone know I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

`debugfs` isn't automated, so you'd have to do it one by one - first `undel` the top level deleted directory, then you can `cd` into it and list deleted files in it (if the directory content was not lost yet), then recover the underlying directories one by one.

You can identify directories in deleted inode lists by looking at the first digit on the second column - if it is `4`, then you are looking at a directory.

BTW - a better alternative would be to use TestDisk. [See this article for example](https://vitux.com/how-to-recover-deleted-files-in-ubuntu-through-testdisk/).

Comment: Just to check. In the example given in https://superuser.com/questions/1045803/how-to-retrieve-deleted-folder-from-linux-mint-server. Here the responder has said that files, etc are in a flat file called recovered.file.001. Is this correct and is it case of somehow recreating this flat file into a directory structure with files?

Comment: In that answer they are looking at a symlink (in some setups - Fedora? - `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`) and then using the journal dump to locate a block on the disk to recover data from using `dd`. This isn't using debugfs' `undel` command, and I'm not sure what is going on there.

Comment: I am looking at a Centos 7 OS and I am slightly limited on options to install other tools. Therefore, I am limited to what is there. In other words I am looking at with the options open to me the easiest way out. So, is it possible to get debugfs or if another tool exists in Centos 7 to recursively recover files from a specific point/location

Comment: I am not aware of any such tool. Even in TestDisk you have to recover one by one (IIRC). TestDisk is available from EPEL, so it should be easy to get by running `yum install epel-release` then `yum install testdisk`.

Comment: testdisk does not work with XFS. Just tested.